# central_logger gem - document size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Anybody else using "customink"'s central_logger gem with mongodb?

I've noticed my collection size doesn't hold nearly as many document as one would expect.  For instance a 250MBs collection holds only 255-260 documents.  I've inserted documents on my own into that very same collection and got upwards of 2000... yet everytime central_logger adds a document into the collection, the number of documents shrink all of a sudden and the avg document size grows exponentially.

As if central_logger inserts its document with somekind of a hidden buffer.

Anybody encountered that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the good folks at mongodb-users google group we have figured out that the problem was me using the "god" gem.

Watch for .megabytes/.kilobytes being turned into numbers you did not expect.

My collections in essence were 250KBs instead of megabytes.